# Adding Items with BOOL Value YES to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Below are a bunch of social media names attached to boolean values that are being pulled from NSUserDefaults. In a previous view, users have the ability to use UISwitches to determine the value of the boolean variable. Here, I simply wish to display only the social medias in which the user has previously switched on (BOOL YES). However, when I log the mutable array, It doesn't even output. As it stands, the array "medias" outputs 1s and 0s accordingly. Would a dictionary be a better idea?

ViewController.m

```
self.oneTableView.dataSource = self;
self.oneTableView.delegate = self;

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *facebook = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"facebook"]];
NSNumber *twitter = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"twitter"]];
NSNumber *instagram = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"instagram"]];
NSNumber *tumblr = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"tumblr"]];
NSNumber *gmail = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"gmail"]];
NSNumber *linkedin = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"linkedin"]];
NSNumber *github = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"github"]];
NSNumber *youtube = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"youtube"]];
NSNumber *vine = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"vine"]];
NSNumber *soundcloud = [NSNumber numberWithBool:[prefs boolForKey:@"soundcloud"]];

NSArray *medias = @[facebook, twitter, instagram, tumblr, gmail, linkedin, github, youtube, vine, soundcloud];

NSLog(@"%@", medias);
int i;

NSMutableArray *includedMedias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (i=0; i <= 10; i+=1) {
    if ([medias[i] intValue] == 1) {
        [includedMedias addObject:medias[i]];
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Included Media: %@", includedMedias);
self.tableData = [includedMedias mutableCopy];
self.oneTableView.editing = YES;
```

**EDIT:**

ViewController.m (From previous view controller storing the keys):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *socialValues = @{@"facebook": @NO,
                                   @"twitter": @NO,
                                   @"instagram": @NO,
                                   @"tumblr": @NO,
                                   @"gmail": @NO,
                                   @"linkedin": @NO,
                                   @"github": @NO,
                                   @"youtube": @NO,
                                   @"vine": @NO,
                                   @"soundcloud": @NO
                                   };
}

- (void)setupOneCell:(setupOneCell *)cell switchValueDidChange:(BOOL)switchValue {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.oneTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSString *label = [self.medias[indexPath.row] socialMedia];

    NSString *newLabel = [label.lowercaseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [self.socialValues setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:switchValue] forKey:newLabel];

    [defaults setObject:self.socialValues forKey:@"valueDict"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

ViewController.m (Pulling the data from UserDefaults):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.oneTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.oneTableView.delegate = self;
    NSMutableArray *includedMedias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *mediaDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"valueDict"];
    for (NSString *key in mediaDict.allKeys) {
        if ([mediaDict[key] intValue] == 1) {
            [includedMedias addObject:key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that you're unhappy that it stores `1`'s and `0`'s instead of `YES` and `NO`?

Comment: @Undo No, It stores YES and NO that NSNumber converts to 1s and 0s. Im unhappy that I can't separate the labels of the 1s in to an array and post them to a table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is this part

```
}else{
    return;
}
```

As soon as that code finds something that's not selected, it returns from the method, and hence never reaches the `NSLog` or the `mutableCopy`.

---

Having said that, you can simplify the code quite a bit by creating an array of media names, and then iterating through that to create the `includedMedias` array.

```
self.oneTableView.dataSource = self;
self.oneTableView.delegate = self;

NSArray *medias = @[@"facebook", @"twitter", @"instagram", @"tumblr", @"gmail",
                    @"linkedin", @"github", @"youtube", @"vine", @"soundcloud"];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *includedMedias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for ( NSString *media in medias )
{
    if ( [prefs boolForKey:media] )
        [includedMedias addObject:media];
}

NSLog(@"Included Media: %@", includedMedias);
self.tableData = [includedMedias mutableCopy];
self.oneTableView.editing = YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to have your user defaults store a single dictionary whose keys would be the media names, and the values would be NSNumbers for the BOOL values. You could then loop through the keys (received from the allKeys method) and add the key string to your mutable array if the value associated with that key is 1.

```
    NSMutableArray *includedMedias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *mediaDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"mediaDict"];
    for (NSString *key in mediaDict.allKeys) {
        if ([mediaDict[key] intValue] == 1) {
            [includedMedias addObject:key];
        }
    }
```